# paypal with prestashop - SetExpressCheckout with prices with more than 2 decimal places

Tags: api, paypal, prestashop

I'd like to include paypal to my prestashop-shop.

Unfortunately the prices in the paypal-checkout are totally messed up due to rounding issues.

The problem is that paypal only accepts 2 decimal places for the item price
but my item prices have up to 4 decimal places.

In prestashop I'm using a price-unit to keep the price readable for the customers.

For example:

```
Item a -> price: 0,0950 €
price-unit -> €/100 mtrs
shown item price in shop: 9,50 €/100 mtrs
```

If a customer buys 60 mtrs from item a he has to pay: 5,70 €.

Paypal only accepts a price of 0,09 or 0,10 € and so the checkout shows 5,40 € or 6,00 €.

Is there any way to get the correct price to paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to fix this through PayPal, as PayPal only accepts a 2 decimal amount.  I am not that familar with PrestaShop but you could possibly modify the code to calculate the amounts different on your side with the cart, but ultimately you will still run into the same issue when you pass over the amount to PayPal.  It will only support the 2 decimal places.

Comment: This is really great :(. So I can forget about PayPal. I tried to take the price * 100 and use a quantity of 0,6. But you can only use integer values for the quantity. I can't believe that paypal is this inflexible. It is not uncommon in the market to have quantities with digits or prices with more than 2 decimal places.

Comment: I can pass this along to our development team as a feature request, but I wouldn't know when or if it would be implemented.

Comment: Hey, that would be a start ;).